# AWS ec2 instance high CPU Usage

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a ec2 instance that has around 10% usage on average. Sometimes we get spikes that are around 95% - at which we have an alert that triggers so we can check the log. I've checked the log and it looks as if another company owned site crawled our site a bunch of times causing the high spike, which triggered a mysql error to a php script no longer in production. Is this normal for a site to spike out your server?

Comment: How frequent are the crawl requests, which instance type you are using and are you exposing urls which request for some heavy data processing. Plz update

Comment: Every couple of days are the requests. Im currently using an ec2 micro instance and not exposing the urls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's possible for a spike in network requests to increase CPU Utilization and if the network load is heavy enough it can most certainly cause a spike to 100% CPU.

Regarding your MySQL error in your PHP script, this was likely because your database couldn't handle any more connections, and connecting to your database in script failed. If you log errors, you should look into the details of the error. If you don't log errors, you should start doing so.

To verify this network spike caused this CPU spike to 100%, use CloudWatch - it's your friend. Open up the NetworkIn and CPU Utilization graphs for your instance and make sure you're looking at the 'Maximum' statistic. Compare the graphs and observe if the Network spikes are reflected in the CPU spikes.

If you're receiving traffic from an unwanted source, block their IPs using Network ACLS (NACLS):
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html

If you regularly experience high levels of traffic on this instance, you should considering moving to Auto Scaling. With Auto Scaling you can have multiple nodes serve your site through an ELB. A web request is sent to your domain name, which is caught by the ELB and then forwarded to a node in the Auto Scaling Group. With Auto Scaling, you can use CloudWatch alarms to allow your infrastructure to scale dynamically. Eg. When the average CPU Utilization of my servers reach 70%, launch an additional server to spread the load. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsAutoScaling.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elastic-load-balancing.html

Here is a great tutorial on how to achieve this architecture:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-register-lbs-with-asg.html

But to put a simple answer to your question, yes it's normal for a big spike in network to overload your instance's CPU.

Answer (score 4):

- You can have a haproxy server in place to avoid unwanted requests if there is any pattern in urls. Keep updating as time goes.
- Always have a 404 error page when the url doesnot match and don't redirect to home page as it reduces the load on server. This can be ignored if your home page is very light and with not much data queries.

Check the load on increasing the no of users, with every new request track how the cpu utilization goes up.

You cannot avoid unwanted request totally but possibly reduce it to some level.

Also a behavior of micro instance i have observed, once it reaches 100% or close to that. It takes some seconds to come back even if no further requests are made.
Micro instances are possibly not good for production if you expect unwanted traffic at times.

Regarding your error, it could be due to lack of available ram and mysql went into deadlock state or something similar.
I'll further update this later.

Answer (score 1):

People usually face this situation when public URLs of the site gets registered on google/bing or any other bot and the bot comes to crawl each url once in a day or two, which results in high CPU utilization at that point of time and it's normal. I have also faced this issue before. If it is from google bot you can remove or deregister from there, for other sites you will need to figure out any custom solution.